# NetworkOnMainThreadException with RxJava 2 + Retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2, networkonmainthread

I'm working on a large codebase with a lot of network calls.  It currently works with Retrofit 1.9 and RxJava 1.x.  But, we're trying to go to RxJava 2.x.

I currently keep getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on our RxJava 2 code.  I'm using RxJava 2.x and Retrofit 1.9.  The plan is to go to Retrofit 2.x later.  But, for now, we need to make this work with RxJava 2 + Retrofit 1.9.

The code in question is:

```
observable
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Void response) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onSuccess(response);
        }   
    }   

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onError(e);
        }   
    }   

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        //do nothing for now 
    }   
});
```

Any ideas how the network operation is ending up on the UI thread when I told it to `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`?

Edit: by request here's the stacktrace.  I genericized filenames and such because I'm not allowed to divulge those details...

```
    retrofit.RetrofitError
     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
     at <package-name>.network.api.$Proxy40.someApiMethod(Unknown Source)
     at <package-name>.SomeApi.someApiMethod(SomeApi.java:30)
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1425)
     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:224)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:193)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:113)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:344)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:329)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
     at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: There is nothing prior to the `at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)` line?

Comment: There is, it's just a call from our custom OkClient class's code to retrofit's OkClient.execute().

Comment: This should not matter, if I understand this correctly... but try moving your `observeOn()` call to be after the `subscribeWith()` call.

Comment: OK, I swapped the lines around and then tried on a Nexus 5X with Android O DP3 and an emulator with 7.0.  Same error occurs on both after the change.

Comment: That's kinda what I thought. Not sure what's going on here... sorry!

Comment: Are you using [RxJava2Interop library](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop)? I think Retrofit 1.X only works with RxJava1

Comment: What is `observable`?  Post also that code

Comment: @GVillani82 It's a io.reactivex.Observable that does a retrofix 1.9 network call to a web service.  As mentioned on the stacktrace, this is company code and I can't divulge too many specifics.  In this case, it's of the form: interface Service { Observable<T> someApiMethod(); } and called via: getService().someApiMethod() where getService() returns a Service created by retrofit.RestAdapter.create().  That's probably as specific as I can be.

Comment: I've had this exact same problem also (a NetworkOnMainThreadException with RxJava 2 + Retrofit 1.9) and I've had to move to Retrofit 2 to fix it.